# How to set a function to ignore variables with no value or non-numeric values

Tags: variables, null

I am using JavaScript in a Google Sheets environment:

I am going to have 5 cells that I'll enter data for.  Sometimes the cells will be blank and sometimes they will have a letter instead of a number.  When I have:
100, 100, 100, 100, 100
I correctly get 500.

I need the function to add numbers correctly when there are less than 5 values and I need it to function correctly when one of the cells is a letter and I need the sum of the other cells.  My code is below.  I just tried to fix the variable d1 as a test.  When I get that figured out, I can fix the other variables.

```
    function WeeklySum(Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri) {
  var d1
  var d2
  var d3
  var d4
  var d5

  if (isEmpty(Mon)){
    d1 = 0
  }
  else{
  d1 = Mon
  }

  d2 = Tue
  d3 = Wed
  d4 = Thu
  d5 = Fri


  return d1+d2+d3+d4+d5
}
```

Comment: which programming language? Please **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I updated the question to show the language as well as what I have attempted thus far.

Comment: What is `isEmpty`? Do you know about [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)?

Comment: isEmpty was supposed to indicate the cell selected for Mon had no valid in it.   I know there are different types of data and it seems that I need to use different types to make this work: a numerical value, a null value, and a string value.  I need to test for each and the. Have d1 be a different value based on the outcome.    I don't know whether an if/else statement would be better or a switch statement.